# WP7 ListBoxItem ContentPresenter Measure Time

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Hopefully someone can help me or at least enlighten me a bit. After the release of the Mango Beta tools I have played a lot with the new WP7 Profiler and one thing does bothers me.

Every single listbox with just a bit more complicated items is taking forever to draw. For an example - a  listbox that has item consisting of Border->Grid->6xTextBoxes (each showing single symbol) takes 303ms per listbox item. Of them 288ms are spent for the ListBoxItem's ContentPresenter Measure Time (excl.).

I know that Measure is kind of costly operation but still this is beyond madness. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can only confirm that MeasureOverride uses to be the most time-consuming operation. (And you don't need a profiler to find it out.) I can only guess why does it take so long.

First, MeasureOverride travels recursively through the visual tree of the ListBoxItem. Somewhere at the end of this call chain there's probably a call into native code that returns actual size.

Hence keeping simple item structure is of utmost importance.

Your structure seems to be overcomplicated. If you look at TextBox template, you will see that its structure is Grid > Border > ContentPresenter. I can't judge what is behind the ContentPresenter since I don't know your code, I just wonder why don't you use TextBlock (where possible) - it is so much more efficient.

As an experiment I would try to implement MyListBoxItem.MeasureOverride and return fixed size without calling base implementation. I have no idea if it works, but it could bring surprising results.

Second thing you may investigate when implementing your own list items is the frequency of the calls to MeasureOverride. (Or just look at the profiler output.) If the number of calls is too high, then the layout might take more loops than necessary. Perhaps there are some conflicting sizing requirements which need several steps to resolve.

You mention 40 items. That should not play any role. ListBox constructs around 3 screens of ListBoxItem's, remaining items are constructed (most often reused) on as-needed basis. If the Measure time increases by increasing the item number, then look for problem in the data implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. These 40 items are actually in one screen (there's a wrap panel). BTW I am using TextBlocks, sorry for the confusion. The sizes are fine and it's not being called many times so there must be sth else. I have tried manually setting all possible sizes with no effect. Will play some more with seizes and might try implementing the MeasureOverride to see if I can improve it. Thanks again for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your data is fully loaded in an async action and only adding item to your ListBox is running on UI Thread
2. Make sure you use Grid instead of StackPanel in your template

The following article is also very useful:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2010/10/06/silverlight-for-windows-phone-7-listbox-scroll-performance.aspx

Comment: Thanks but the data is locally calculated and is deffinately not the problem as it takes just a few ms to produce. I really would like to hear some ideas regarding the Measure issue

Comment: Have you followed recommendations in the link I included? I generally follow those ones and haven't yet had a major problem in my two submitted apps.

Comment: Well over the last months I have come across most of the suggestions and tried them but with no success. The sizes are fixed, there is no data being downloaded and I have a few items (around 40 listbox items). Still measuring phaze takes longer than it makes sense.